# NSNetService delegates not being called

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, bonjour

I'm trying to resolve a NSNetService (named "My_Mac") to an IP in a background app with this code:

```
NSNetService *service = [[NSNetService alloc] initWithDomain:@"local." type:@"_daap._tcp" name:@"My_Mac"];
[service setDelegate:self];
[service resolveWithTimeout:5];
```

And in the same class, I have these delegate methods defined:

```
- (void)netServiceDidResolveAddress:(NSNetService *)sender
- (void)netService:(NSNetService *)sender didNotResolve:(NSDictionary *)errorDict
```

Here's the strange part: neither delegate methods get called unless I run a NSAlert after   "[service resolveWithTimeout:5];". Any ideas?

Answer (score 31):

If you are using ARC you need to retain the service object somewhere. 
In your example, the service object most likely goes out of scope and is not referenced anywhere else in your code, so the compiler will try to release it immediately after the resolve call.

Add a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *services;
```

In your delegate, or wherever you use NSNetService

```
- (void)netServiceBrowser:(NSNetServiceBrowser *)browser
           didFindService:(NSNetService *)aNetService
               moreComing:(BOOL)moreComing
{
    if (!self.services) {
        self.services = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    [self.services addObject:aNetService];
    [aNetService setDelegate:self];
    [aNetService resolveWithTimeout:3.0];
}
```

Don't forget to stop and release those services once you're finished or getting rid of the delegate:

```
for (NSNetService* service in self.services) {
    [service stop];
}
[self.services removeAllObjects];
```

Comment: retaining it works. But doesn't the NSNetService parameter in the NSNetServiceDelegate method signatures retain the object? e.g. **sender** in `- (void)netServiceDidResolveAddress:(NSNetService *)sender`

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure, but it looks like the request is not actually scheduled in a run loop for some reason.  Maybe try something like [this](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/CocoaSOAP/listing10.html) to schedule it?

```
NSNetService *service = [[[NSNetService alloc] initWithDomain:@"local." type:@"_daap._tcp." name:@"My_Mac"] autorelease];
[service setDelegate:self];
[service scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:@"PrivateMyMacServiceMode"];
[service resolveWithTimeout:8.0];
```

Stupid question, but are you explicitly implementing [NSServiceDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSNetServiceDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSNetServiceDelegate) protocol or just have the methods?

EDIT: I had another thought that this might be some kind of race condition (a more likely scenario).  Delegates are usually weak references.  If your object is dropping out of scope and being autoreleased, the system would end up with a nil handle and be firing the messages to nil.  In the case where you show an NSAlert (or do other work) your object might be hanging around just long enough for it to get the messages fired back to it.  Could you confirm your object sticks around for the full 8 seconds?

Comment: Thanks for the reply slf. I tried the NSRunLoop code you had, but no dice. I just have the methods since I'm targeting 10.5 which doesn't have the formal NSServiceDelegate protocol defined.

Comment: slf: you're right - I turned off GC to make sure the object was still there, and the delegates were called. Now I just have to track down where it's being autoreleased, since I've explicitly tried retaining it, and that didn't work. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: the solution to seemingly complex problems is usually simpler than you first think :)

Comment: An explicit retain of the `NSNetService` object right after `resolveWithTimeout` fixed the same problem for me, too. I'm new to iPhone development, but damn! stuff like this is irritating. I guess the motto for Mac/iPhone programming should be "it just doesn't work".

Comment: I was just creating serviceBrowser object in ViewDidLoad without having a reference of it in controller as a property! so this caused the object being dropped out and released after method scope.

Answer (score 0):

I've just run into this problem and I was already retaining the `NSNetService` object so that wasn't the reason.

Turns it out it was because the access levels of the delegate methods I defined wasn't matching the access level of the `class` (the `class` was `public` while the delegate methods were `internal`). And because all of the delegate methods are optional, the compiler was just giving a silent warning.